# how to get value in str in python (not in array/list format)

Tags: python, list, csv

I have been trying to pick the value in str with each pop(). Here by my code that i have been trying:

```
  with open('resources/CSV/numbers.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        print(reader)
        CREDENTIALS = list(reader)
        print(CREDENTIALS)
        number = CREDENTIALS.pop()
        print("value of number is:" + str(number))
```

The format if the csv contains number:

1000399094
1000399095
1000399096
1000399097
1000399098
1000399099
1000399100
1000399101
1000399102

Output is:

> [['1000399094'], ['1000399095'], ['1000399096'], ['1000399097'], ['1000399098'], ['1000399099'], ['1000399100'], ['1000399101'], ['1000399102']]

> value of number is:['1000399102']

The problem here is that i need value in 1000399102 not ['1000399102'] as i'm new to python i'm unable to find any solution for the same.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, debugging, or tutorial service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You access the item you want with the appropriate index.  You extract the string and convert to int.  Repeat your tutorials on data types (for `int`) and list access.

Comment: Why are you calling `list(reader)`?  That's an unusual way to do it.

Comment: @NotZack , i didn't find anything which is against the guidelines with my question.

Comment: @JohnGordon as there are multiple values i wanted to keep them in list and pop one after another to access all the values. I know there are another way to do so as well but for some reason i'm bounded to follow this way only.

Comment: Using `list(reader)` reads the _entire_ file and puts all the values in a list.  Do you really want to do that?

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks for replying , i'm going forward with Sushil answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple `list comprehension` should help you:

```
lst = [['1000399094'], ['1000399095'], ['1000399096'], ['1000399097'], ['1000399098'], ['1000399099'], ['1000399100'], ['1000399101'], ['1000399102']]

lst = [[int(num)] for lstt in lst for num in lstt]

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[[1000399094], [1000399095], [1000399096], [1000399097], [1000399098], [1000399099], [1000399100], [1000399101], [1000399102]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Sushil, i wanted to use pop() only to get this result. Is it possible to do using pop()?

Comment: But a list comprehension is better. Do u definitely wanna use `pop()`?

Comment: I know but for some reason i'm bounded to use this way only

Comment: But how do you think that you can convert the values to integers using `pop()`?

Comment: i figured that i can't so i'll go with your answer, thank you